# Use a variable to define multiple functions docstring

Tags: python, docstring

I have several functions (`a`, `b` and `c`), I want them to use the same docstring. So my plan was to conserve lines by only writing the docstring once and save it to a variable `DOCSTRING`. Then I place it under the function declaration. I hadn't found anything in [PEP 257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#what-is-a-docstring) that addresses my problem...

```
DOCSTRING = '''
This is a docstring
for functions:
a,
b,
c'''

def a(x, y):
    DOCSTRING
    # do stuff with x and y

def b(x, y):
    DOCSTRING
    # do other stuffs with x and y

def c(x, y):
    DOCSTRING
    # do some more stuffs with x and y

help(a), help(b), help(c)
```

I actually thought it might work...but I was wrong, I got this:

```
Help on function a in module __main__:

a(x, y)

Help on function b in module __main__:

b(x, y)

Help on function c in module __main__:

c(x, y)
```

It was not at all useful.

---

I made my second attempt, by changing the special `__doc__` attribute of the function to my docstring `DOCSTRING`:

```
DOCSTRING = '''
This is a docstring
for functions:
a,
b,
c'''

def a(x, y):
    a.__doc__ = DOCSTRING # also tried just __doc__ = DOCSTRING, both didn't work
    # do stuff with x and y

def b(x, y):
    b.__doc__ = DOCSTRING # also tried just __doc__ = DOCSTRING, both didn't work
    # do other stuffs with x and y

def c(x, y):
    c.__doc__ = DOCSTRING # also tried just __doc__ = DOCSTRING, both didn't work
    # do some more stuffs with x and y

help(a), help(b), help(c)
```

And the both method got the same output as the previous attempt...

---

What works currently is the good'ole copy-and-paste method:

```
def a(x, y):
    '''
    This is a docstring
    for functions:
    a,
    b,
    c'''

    # do stuff with x and y

def b(x, y):
    '''
    This is a docstring
    for functions:
    a,
    b,
    c'''

    # do other stuffs with x and y

def c(x, y):
    '''
    This is a docstring
    for functions:
    a,
    b,
    c'''

    # do some more stuffs with x and y

help(a), help(b), help(c)
```

And of course, it produces my desired output:

```
Help on function a in module __main__:

a(x, y)
    This is a docstring
    for functions:
    a,
    b,
    c

Help on function b in module __main__:

b(x, y)
    This is a docstring
    for functions:
    a,
    b,
    c

Help on function c in module __main__:

c(x, y)
    This is a docstring
    for functions:
    a,
    b,
    c
```

As you can see, but this way will force me to having to waste multiple lines writing the same thing...

---

So now, my question is, how can I get the same result as if I copied the docstring to every single function, **without** having to copy it to every single function?

Comment: Note that docstrings are, per the PEP you link, *"a **string literal** that occurs as the first statement"*. That's why your first approach cannot work. Your second only works if you call the functions before calling `help`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is that attempting to set docstrings within the function body is not going to work because those lines are never evaluated unless the function is actually called. What you need is something like (or an equivalent of):

```
def c(x, y):
    # code

c.__doc__ = DOCSTRING
help(c)
```

You'd want to use a decorator.

```
def setdoc(func):                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    func.__doc__ = DOCSTRING                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    return func

@setdoc                                                                                                                                                                                                                
def c(x, y):                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    print("hi")                                                                                                                                                                                                              

help(c) #Output docstring
```